# Graph Theory example not accepted by ACL2 Sedan

Tags: acl2

I'm studying the 'An Exercise in Graph Theory' example using the latest version of ACL2 Sedan. Unfortunately ACL2 does not accept the **find-next-step** function.
I've checked several times it's typed in correctly and all functions it invokes are available. 
The first part of the output summary:

*Producing counter-example, including simplifying rulers in order to
maximize the reabability of the counter-example.
The following function definitions correspond to an actual loop in
your function definitions for which the CCG analysis was unable to
prove termination in all cases:*

```
(DEFUN FIND-NEXT-STEP_0 (C STACK B G)
       (IF (AND (CONSP C)
                (NOT (MEMBER-EQUAL (CAR C) STACK))
                (NOT (EQUAL (CAR C) B)))
           (FIND-NEXT-STEP_0 (NEIGHBORS (CAR C) G)
                             (CONS (CAR C) STACK)
                             B G)
           (LIST C STACK B G)))
```

Being a novice, before I turn to finding out what's wrong by myself, I'd like to make sure the book text should run on the Sedan version.
It's also possible I'm not aware of some necessary settings and book inclusions.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What mode are you running it on?

Comment: ACL2s - full-featured with CCG termination analysis.

Comment: What book are you referring to?